# Not sure how to exclude number values from my output

Tags: c++, char, int, ascii

using C++ I have made this code to determine when a user inputs a value if it is an upper case or lowercase value or not a value at all that part is easy for me and I have additionally made it so the output will also  convert a lowercase input into an uppercase input and an uppercase input into a lowercase input my proffesort has only allowed us to use if else statments meaning no arrays or vectors and I am not sure how to exclude my code from converting if it is a number value I am totally lost in using this ascii table. Please help Below is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char Letter; //defines the char variable letter for the user to input a value

cout<< "Please input a letter :)!" << endl;
cin>> Letter;

    if ( Letter>= 65 && Letter <= 90) //checks the acsii dec values to see if the input is a
        cout<< "This is an uppercase letter!"<<endl;//lowercase letter
else  if (Letter >= 97 && Letter <= 122)//checks to see if the acsii dec value is 
          cout<< "This is a lower case letter!"<<endl;//uppercase
      else 
          cout<<"This is not a letter :("<<endl;//outputs this if the acsii value is not a letter

if (Letter >=65&& Letter <= 90)
{
    Letter+=32;
    cout<< Letter<<" "<<"This is the Lowercase of your uppercase letter!\n";
}
else  (Letter >= 97 && Letter <=122);
{
    Letter-=32;
    cout<< Letter<<" "<<"This is the Uppercase of your lowercase letter!\n";
}

system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: No need for assuming ASCII. Use `std::(is|to)(lower|upper)` and `std::isalpha` for the is letter check.

Comment: I literally can not use those std I can only use the header I input into my code already and my teacher said Im supposed to use ascii I'm only allowed to use if else statements and conditions

Comment: Just the way I have done the code implementing -= and += 32 for the corresponding ascii code values when I input 1 or 2 I get the ascii values for that changed to and I'm not sure how to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here:

```
else  (Letter >= 97 && Letter <=122);
```

I guess you want to write:

```
else if (Letter >= 97 && Letter <=122);
    ^^^^
```

By the way, you can make your code smaller if just reorder your code to improve locallity:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char Letter; //defines the char variable letter for the user to input a value

  cout<< "Please input a letter :)!" << endl;
  cin>> Letter;

  if ( Letter>= 65 && Letter <= 90) {
    cout<< "This is an uppercase letter!"<<endl;
    Letter+=32;
    cout<< Letter<<" "<<"This is the Lowercase of your uppercase letter!\n";
  } else  if (Letter >= 97 && Letter <= 122) {
    cout<< "This is a lower case letter!"<<endl;
    Letter-=32;
    cout<< Letter<<" "<<"This is the Uppercase of your lowercase letter!\n";
  } else 
    cout<<"This is not a letter :("<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I give you karma or anything or something or anything for helping me I am very new to this site :)

Comment: Wellcome to stackoverflow. I suggest you just to give a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/about it is a good way to start over

Comment: yeah sorry I dont have enough rep to upvote you :p If I could I definitely would however :)

Answer (score 0):

As of now your codes works for only alphabets, any how if the user input is not a alphabet, it'll not do anything, i don;t understand what you want to exclude from your code? you mean to say instead of assci values you want to use some other thing.

In that case you can use the following code, which will avoid the complete ASCIIs value you need to worry or remember the ascii numbers

```
 if ( Letter>= 'A' && Letter <= 'Z') //checks the acsii dec values to see if the input is a
    cout<< "This is an uppercase letter!"<<endl;//lowercase letter
else  if (Letter >= 'a' && Letter <= 'z')//checks to see if the acsii dec value is 
      cout<< "This is a lower case letter!"<<endl;//uppercase
  else 
      cout<<"This is not a letter :("<<endl;//outputs this if the acsii value is not a letter

 if (Letter >='A'&& Letter <= 'Z')
 {
   Letter+='a'-'A';
    cout<< Letter<<" "<<"This is the Lowercase of your uppercase letter!\n";
 }
 else  (Letter >= 'a' && Letter <='z');
 {
   Letter-='a'-'A';
   cout<< Letter<<" "<<"This is the Uppercase of your lowercase letter!\n";
  }
```

Comment: and you can combine the repetitive conditions into one

Comment: what was happening was I was asking the user to input something ideally a letter and then I would use the dec ascii values to print that value onto the screen defined as an upper or lwoercase value and then would use the ascii table in order to convert the input value to its opposite. For example if the user input 'a' I would cconvert it to 'A' However through the code I had writte if they had input 1 I would get the ascii value for 1 +=32 and -= 32 However thanks to others help I have fixed it :)